# Creating method in implementation without defining in header

Tags: objective-c, encapsulation

How can I create a method in the @implementation of a class without defining it in the @interface?

For example, I have a constructor that does some initialisation and then reads data from a file.  I want to factor out the file-reading code into a separate method that I then call from within the constructor.  I don't want to define this method in the header because it's private only to this @implementation context.

Is this possible?

Here's my example.  I have a little program that read's a Todo task-list from a file.

Here is the @interface:

```
@interface TDTaskList : NSObject {
  NSString* name; // The name of this list.
  NSMutableArray* tasks;  // The set of tasks in this list.
}

-(id)initListOfName:(NSString*)aName;
-(NSArray*)loadListWithName:(NSString*)aName;

@end
```

And here is part of the @implementation:

```
-(id)initListOfName:(NSString*)aName {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    name = aName;

    NSArray* aTasks = [self loadListWithName:aName];
    tasks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:aTasks];
  }

  return self;
}

-(NSArray*)loadListWithName:(NSString*)aName {
  // TODO This is a STUB till i figure out how to read/write from a file ...

  TDTask* task1 = [[TDTask alloc] initWithLabel:@"Get the Milk."];
  TDTask* task2 = [[TDTask alloc] initWithLabel:@"Do some homework."];

  return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:task1, task2, nil];
}
```

What I want to do is to **not** have to define the following in the interface:

```
-(NSArray*)loadListWithName:(NSString*)aName;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you place the implementation of a method before any code that calls it you do not need to define it in the header.

So in this case put *loadListWithName:* in front of *initListOfName:* in the @implementation block and it will be good.

**Note:** Just because it is not defined in the header does not mean the method cannot be called by code outside of the object. Objective-C does not have private methods.

Comment: I see what you mean.  So it's as if I'm writing a function outside the scope of this class, right?

Answer (score 6):

As Andy hinted in the comments, you can use [Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_6_section_5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) (which look like a category without a name). The difference is that you *must* implement the methods declared in an extension whereas the compiler doesn't verify that you implement methods declared in a category.

.h:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    NSNumber *number;
}
- (NSNumber *)number;
@end
```

.m:

```
@interface MyObject ()
- (void)setNumber:(NSNumber *)newNumber;
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (NSNumber *)number
{
    return number;
}
- (void)setNumber:(NSNumber *)newNumber
{
    number = newNumber;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Categories):

```
// In TDTaskList.m
@interface TDTaskList(TDTaskListPrivate)
-(id)initListOfName:(NSString*)aName;
-(NSArray*)loadListWithName:(NSString*)aName;
@end

@implementation TDTaskList(TDTaskListPrivate)

// implementation of initListOfName and loadListWithName ...

@end
```

Comment: Note that as of Objective-C 2.0 the category name is no longer required for private categories. This helps keep the code a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You have two reasonable options. Both were basically described already but IMHO were a bit unclear or even plain wrong.

Categories are not one of them as they are AFAIK meant for the entirely different purpose of breaking implementations into multiple source files.

Do as Nathan described above. Though he is wrong with his last assumption (private methods).

Use a private method extension definition to allow forward referencing as follows:

1. remove the definition of loadListWithName from your header entirely
2. add the following into the source (.m) before the @implementation block

```
@interface TDTaskList (PrivateMethods)
-(NSArray*)loadListWithName:(NSString*)aName;
@end

@implementation ...
```